# VueJs within AngularJs - How to stop AngularJs from intercepting VueJs-specific routes

Tags: angularjs, vue.js, angular-ui-router

I maintain a (legacy) large scale ecommerce web app (built with AngularJS) and I'm rebuilding it from scratch with VueJs.

The two apps **have** to co-exist unfortunately (until all existing features are rewritten in VueJs), meaning as I rebuild features on VueJs, we migrate users to that new component (or page, or feature) instead of the legacy one.

There's no issues doing that, i can setup config files etc to setup routing from component to component.

The catch however, is the VueJS app HAS to live within the AngularJs app. This is due to many factors, one of them SEO (no option to use subdomains), complicated deployment, among many others.

I've done what i need to do to get the VueJs app to exist inside the AngularJs app, and mostly everything works, with the exception of one specific routing issue.

Here's a very rough structure after my `build` command is run:

- /dist <---- AngularJs app root

  - index.html
  - /app

    - app.js
    - app.css
  - /vue <---- VueJs app root

    - index.html
    - ...etc

When the user lands on `site.com/vue`, vue takes over, and internal `<router-link>`'s work fine.

The problem is when a user specifically types something like this in the address bar `site.com/vue/page-1`. AngularJs intercepts that and basically calls it a 404.

I TRIED to tackle the issue by creating a UI-router state which has a specific url of `/vue/:page`, matching the folder of my VueJs app location. But that's not really doing its job properly.

I also tried listening to route changes on ui-router's `$stateChangeStart`, but that can become expensive very quickly.

Can anyone think of a way to fix this? Very bizarre set of circumstances i know, but i don't have much choice with the way of the overall architecture unfortunately.

Comment: what web/app/ui server are you using for server side routing?

Comment: There's no server side routing. All handled within AngularJs on the legacy app, and the rest by VueJs inside that app. The app (and the new app within it) are hosted on S3 (if that helps)

Answer (score 1):

After user types url - browser send new http request and it is up to your server what to return. (This has nothing to do with js or UI in general) I guess your server returns angular index.html for not-found routes and you can easily change this.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I can easily change this on the server end you mean?

Comment: If I am right yes. Of course, I can not know for sure what's going on in your app.